# Is it possible to use .mlmodel in Android, trained with playground (Xcode)?

Tags: android, machine-learning, mlmodel

There is so few material about Android application examples.
Could someone answer is it possible to use .mlmodel trained with playground in the Android project?

[Official sources](https://developer.android.com/ml) refers to ML Kit, TensorFlow Lite and AutoML.

[Moreover, there is detailed example of use](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models) for  Android SDK level 16.

But:

> (usually ending in .tflite or .lite)

Could you give me any constructive advice or an knowledge I should have to complete the Android project trained with Machine Learning model?

I believe, this information would be useful for every beginner interested in Android development also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Can I convert mlmodel files back to tflite?](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/issues/327) the answer appears to be **no**.

From what I can tell, the `.mlmodel` format is a client-end inference model similar to `.tflite` where [.tflite is a minimized format for deployment on device](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started#2_convert_the_model_format).
I suspect that in the process of conversion from the original full machine learning model, trade-offs are made which may or may not have equivalents between the two formats.